# How to removes all instances of thumbnails displayed in my theme?

Tags: filters, hooks, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

basically I'd like all thumbnails mentions to be replaced by an empty string or something like that. Some piece of code I can just add to a plugin or functions.php

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE. Could you please elaborate why? Because if it's about the thumbnails, you can totally disable them.

Comment: How can I disable them? The reason is cause I made a plugin that adds my own thumbnails from a different source so I dont need them. And I need an additive solution, because it needs to be compatible with every theme. I can't edit every theme each time. @JackJohansson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing such thing by replacing the URL is not recommended, for a variety of reasons. One for example is that if you do this, your thumbnails won't be deleted after you delete the original image, since you have broken the link in the database.

Another reason is that if you try to access a default-size generated thumbnail, it will redirect to a simple page load. For example:

> http://example.com/uploads/test.jpg

becomes:

> http://example.com/

This means a full request to the homepage, loading every asset, requesting more links, and go on.

The correct approach would be to unset the default sizes. You can hook into `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` filter and do this:

```
function unset_default_thumbnails( $sizes) {
    unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['medium-large']);
    unset( $sizes['large']);

    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'unset_default_thumbnails');
```

Done. Now, there will be no generated thumbnails after you upload an image. Your own thumbnail sizes still will be generated.

To delete the current thumbnails, you can use the popular [Thumbnail Cleaner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/thumbnail-cleaner/) plugin.

### UPDATE

Based on your comments, I've added a way to replace the URLs generated by `the_post_thumbnail()` with an empty string. This is ***not*** recommended.

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'disable_post_thumbnails' ,10 , 5 );
function disable_post_thumbnails( $html, $post->ID, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ){
    // Check if the image is true
    if ( $html ) {
        switch ( $size ) {
            case 'post-thumbnail':
            case 'thumbnail':
            case 'medium':
            case 'medium-large':
            case 'large':
                // Let's replace the thumbnail's URL with the
                // website's URL for only the default sizes
                $html = str_replace( $html , '<img src="'.site_url().'"/>' , $html );
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    // Return the URL
    return $html;
}
```

Please notice, once a function is declared you can't just remove it. What you can do is to filter it's input/output, if it does support that.

**PS:** this can break plugin/theme's behavior. This is just for educational purposes, do not try this at home.

Comment: why not recommended? he can just remove all the connections to featured images on all the posts without breaking anything. He can do it manually or use some code to do that

Comment: I meant replacing the URL with an empty string is not.

Comment: agree, but I have a feeling he is not married to that specific idea

Comment: :D I did it once on a portfolio blog which had about 30 images on home page. Took a look at my console, and there we hundreds of 404 requests because of this. PS: I use @ in case the comments are deleted later, so the reader is not confused about unrelated comments.

Comment: btw you do not need to mention the person which is the author of the latest comment, the notification is done automagically

Comment: Thanks, very useful, is there a way to "deactivate" hooks? Like for example I want the_post_thumbnail() to do nothing. Is that possible just from adding code to functions.php? @JackJohansson

Comment: You're welcome @DanyM. That one is really not recommended, many plugins depend on it, wouldn't you agree @MarkKaplun? By the way it's not a hook, `the_post_thumbnail()` is a function. But if you insist, I can add a ... solution for that too.

Comment: @JackJohansson That would be awesome yes, it would fix my problem I think. It's for personal use so even if it causes conflicts it doesn't matter.

Comment: I've updated the answer for you. @DanyM